# WebStorm - CSS remove blank spaces from Code Reformat

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm automatically adds blank lines after every CSS selector definitions, after I try to reformat CSS/Sass/SCSS code. Is it possible to disable this behavior?

[image]

Comment: This raises a question:  why?  Separating these out visibly improves readability.

Comment: I don't see how it improves readability, never had a problem spotting where CSS declarations begin and end. This simply adds some unnecessary lines to CSS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | CSS | Other**, set **Blank lines between blocks** to `0`